# Replace content of one line by checking previous and next line

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am trying to replace content by checking previous lines as well as the next line. As shown below.

```
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</Info>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth1"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.22</IpAdd>
<port>6789</port>
</Info>
<User>
<avl>"Name"</avl>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</User>
```

Replace `<IpAdd>any IP address</IpAdd>` with `<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>` for which the next line is `<port>1123</port>` and it should be under `<Info><pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>` section.

What I tried:

```
sed -E "/<Info>/{n;/<pInfo>/{n;s@<IpAdd>.*<([^\n]*\n[^\n]*<port>1123</port>)@<IpAdd>111.111.111.111<@}}" test.txt
```

Want to replace in the line above port 1123. If I remove `([^\n]*\n[^\n]*<port>1123</port>)`, then it replaces both ips under Info.

```
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</Info>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth1"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>
<port>6789</port>
</Info>
<User>
<avl>"Name"</avl>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</User>
```

Expect:

```
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</Info>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth1"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.22</IpAdd>
<port>6789</port>
</Info>
<User>
<avl>"Name"</avl>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</User>
```

Comment: Is this part of an XML file?

Comment: @Cyrus, yes it's a part of XML. Don't want an XML-specific solution though for the general scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/<Info>/{:a;N;/<\/Info>$/!ba
        s/(<IpAdd>).*(<\/IpAdd>\n<port>1123<\/port>)/\1111.111.111.111\2/}' file
```

Gather up the lines between `<Info>` and `</Info>` and then match the two lines within the collection that start with `<IpAddr>` and end with `1123</port>` and replace the old address with the new address.

Comment: Thanks for the `sed` solution. What do I need to do if I want to search nested? For e.g., `<Info><item><pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo><IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd><port>1123</port></item><item><pInfo>"eth11"</pInfo><IpAdd>192.168.1.21</IpAdd><port>11231</port></item></Info>`, replace `192.168.1.2` IP only (as its port is 1123).

Comment: @Dr.PB if the above string is formatted as the original one, the above solution should solve either. But if the format is not the same perhaps another question would serve you better.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. There are some spaces in the XML file on/before/after every tag. Used `-E '/<Info>/{:a;N;/<\/Info>$/!ba s/(<IpAdd>).*(<\/IpAdd>\n(\s)*<port>1123<\/port>)/\1111.111.111.111\2/}'`. All the `awk` solutions are great, but I think this one-line soln using `sed` is preferable to me.

Comment: one more question, if I want to use IP from an env variable, i.e., say IP=111.111.111.111, in that case `\1${IP}\2` is not working. Any help?

Comment: @Dr.PB notice the sed commands are enclosed in single quotes. This prevents the shell from interpreting anything within the those quotes. You could replace the single quotes by double quotes and this most likely would do your bidding. However if you want to interpret a shell variable then surround it by single and double quotes i.e. `'"${IP}"'` This has the effect of sandwiching the  variable between to single quoted strings and allows the shell to do its work without sacrificing the goodness of single quotes. BTW the double quotes preserve any spaces (if any) in the shell variable.

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^<Info>/ {
    info = ""
    inInfo = 1
}
inInfo {
    info = (info ? info ORS : "") $0
    if ( /^<\/Info>/ ) {
        $0 = info
        if ( (/<pInfo>"eth0"<\/pInfo>/) && (/<port>1123<\/port>/) ) {
            sub(/<IpAdd>.*<\/IpAdd>/,"<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>")
        }
        inInfo = 0
    }
}
!inInfo
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</Info>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth1"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.22</IpAdd>
<port>6789</port>
</Info>
<User>
<avl>"Name"</avl>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</User>
```

The above assumes that the order of lines within an Info block don't actually matter.

Answer (score 2):

One `awk` idea:

```
eth='eth0'
port='1123'
ip='111.111.111.111'

awk -v eth="${eth}" -v port="${port}" -v newip="${ip}" '     # populate awk variables with OS variable varlues

function update_print() {
    if (block) {                                             # if block is not empty then ...

       # if block contains matches for our "eth" and "port" values then update the block with newip

       if (block ~ "<pInfo>\"" eth "\"</pInfo>"   &&   block ~ "<port>" port "</port>")
          sub(/<IpAdd>.*<\/IpAdd>/, "<IpAdd>" newip "</IpAdd>", block)

       print block                                           # print block
    }

}

$0 == "<Info>"  { inblock = 1 }                              # if start of a new block then set flag
$0 == "</Info>" { update_print()                             # if end of block then update and/or print block
                  block   = ""                               # reset our
                  inblock = 0                                # variables
                }
inblock         { block = block (block ? ORS : "") $0        # if flag is set then append current line to variable "block"
                  next                                       # skip to next input line
                }
1                                                            # if we get here it is because "inblock == 0"; "1" is always true so print current line
' test.xml
```

This generates:

```
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</Info>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth1"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.22</IpAdd>
<port>6789</port>
</Info>
<User>
<avl>"Name"</avl>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</User>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr):

I augmented the data to test more cases: the pattern occurs twice in my `<Info>`, and I have a `<NotInfo>` element in which the pattern occurs, but must not be edited:

```
$ cat xml
<NotInfo>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</NotInfo>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</Info>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth1"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.22</IpAdd>
<port>6789</port>
</Info>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</Info>
<User>
<avl>"Name"</avl>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
<NotInfo>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</NotInfo>
```

It's edited only in the right places:

```
$ txr edit.txr xml
<NotInfo>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</NotInfo>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</Info>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth1"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.22</IpAdd>
<port>6789</port>
</Info>
<Info>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</Info>
<User>
<avl>"Name"</avl>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</User>
<NotInfo>
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
</NotInfo>
```

Where `edit.txr`:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
<Info>
@    (do (put-line "<Info>"))
@    (repeat)
@      (cases)
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>192.168.1.2</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
@        (output)
<pInfo>"eth0"</pInfo>
<IpAdd>111.111.111.111</IpAdd>
<port>1123</port>
@        (end)
@      (or)
@        line
@        (do (put-line line))
@      (end)
@    (last)
</Info>
@    (end)
@  (or)
@    line
@    (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

How it works is that we have an outer `@(repeat)` which is doing a sliding pattern scan, looking for two cases: a block that starts with `<Info>`, or a fallback case which matches one line that can be anything. When the fallback case occurs, the line is output. Whatever is matches is consumed and so the scanning starts with the next line.

The primary case begins with a match for `<Info>`. If that succeeds, then `<Info>` is output and a nested scan takes place similar to the outer one: look for the three-line pattern to be replaced, or else fall back on consuming and outputting one line.   The inner `@(repeat)` terminates when an `</Info>` closing tag is seen.